# How to get time since record submitted to DB?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a searchable user promotion database and when a users promotion is added to this database it includes a hidden field on the form

I am wanting to add on my search form an option to show how long it has been since the last promotion Example being

Name:
Rank:
Promoter:
Last Promotion: XX Minutes Ago or 1hr 15mins

Currently I just have it display the timestamp that was submitted with the promotion record, But in an effort to make it easier on my admins I want to display the amount of time that has lapsed.

This is the code I use to display the information from the database into the form:

```
echo "Name: " .$result['HName']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Last Rank: ".$result['LRank']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Current Rank: ".$result['CRank']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Promoted By: ".$result['Promoter']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Type of Log: ".$result['Type']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Last Promotion: ".$result['Time']; --I want this field to display the difference in time instead of just the timestamp –
```

Comment: This is the code I use to display the information from the database into the form:


echo "Name: " .$result['HName'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Last Rank: ".$result['LRank'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Current Rank: ".$result['CRank'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Promoted By: ".$result['Promoter'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Type of Log: ".$result['Type'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Last Promotion: ".$result['Time']; --I want this field to display the difference in time instead of just the timestamp

Comment: if you have the time saved when the record is inserted, then you can easily calcualte the difference between the saved time and `NOW()`

Comment: Please add the code in question block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below function in your query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2014-04-03 12:00:00','2014-04-03 11:15:00');
```

Comment: Closest to answer lol. I ended up going with this. 

    echo "Last Promotion:<strong> ";
   $start_date = new DateTime($result['Time']);
   $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($result['time()']));
   echo $since_start->d.' days &nbsp;';
   echo $since_start->h.' hours &nbsp;';
   echo $since_start->i.' minutes Ago</strong>';

Answer (score 0):

you should try the Date function in your query

see below example,

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('your db_name', $conn);

$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (CreatedOn) VALUES ('$sqlDate');";

$qur = mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Visit below link and find more example

http://riturajkumar12.blogspot.in/